# How to get last updated date of a oracle database linux when DB is down

Tags: linux, bash, oracle, automation, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to find the last updated date of a DB when the DB is down using bash. I can find few queries like below

```
select * from (select logon_time ,dense_rank() over (order by logon_time desc) ranking from v$session ) where ranking = 2;
```

But these queries work only after I start the DB, which changes the date. I want a way to find the last updated date without starting it. So that I'll be able to decide whether to have it or delete it according to the last updated date in script

Comment: check the timestamp of the dbf files on the file system, that'll tell you when the db was shut down

Comment: if your db is mounted some of the v$ views will be available...

Comment: Thank you @thatjeffsmith. It works.